# Mysql Workbench error 1142 "Error querying security information" on Data Export

Tags: mysql-workbench

yesterday I updated my Workbench to the latest version available, the 6.3.6 build 511 CE on Windows 10.

Now I'm trying to make a dump of a remote database via the "Data Export" feature, which has always worked.

But, as soon as I click the "Start Export" button, I get this error:

> Unhandled exception: Error querying security information: Error
>   executing 'SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '*[username]*' and
>   Host = '*[host]*' ORDER BY User, Host'
>   SELECT command denied to user '*[username]*'@'*[host]*' for table 'user'
>   SQL Error: 1142

I know that I don't have the permissions to read that table, but why is that needed to perform a data export?

I've tried to check the force option (`Continue even if we get an sql-error`) but it's still not working.

Is this a Workbench bug? Or is there any way to avoid this query?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update as of 13th June 2016**

[This bug has now been fixed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79807)

Download 6.3.7 (or later if available) from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

Comment: When I download [mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-1ubu1604-amd64.deb](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=463710), I get an error in Ubuntu Software Center saying "Dependency is not satisfiable: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>=2.24.0).  Can that dependency be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 or do I need to upgrade to 16.04 to make this version of MySQL Workbench work?

Comment: Ugh. Workbench 6.3.7 doesn't support 14.04 anymore.  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81869

Comment: Warning: the proposed default installer in that link (MySQL Installer 5.7 for Windows) doesn't work. The workbench version inside this installer is 6.3.6 (instead of the 6.3.7). Under "other downloads" there is this "Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer" (mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-win32.msi) which works correctly.

Comment: For Mac OS X as of Aug 2016, the latest version in the website is 6.3.7 but the "Check for Update" of 6.3.6 said it's the latest version. The "Check for Update" feature is also bugged.

Comment: Seems like as of today (8th may 2018) the newest version in ubuntu repositories is 6.3.6 so if you need to update in Ubuntu >=16.04 then you need to go to https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ an get yourself a proper DEB file and install it from that file.

Answer (score 28):

I had this exact same issue. The solution provided in [this thread](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79807) (same as [the_nuts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522129/3376401)) is to uninstall 6.3.6 and install 6.3.4 from the archived versions: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: Just tested on CentOS 7.2, version 6.3.4 does not present this problem.

Comment: Wow mysql workbench is really bad... 6 months passed and they still can't be bothered to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Found, this is indeed a bug of the version 6.3.6:

[MySQL Bugs: #79807: Workbench Data Export: Unhandled exception: Error querying security information](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79807)

Answer (score -5):

MySQL Workbench has the correct behavior. If you are using a user other than 'root' MySQL Workbench will display that alert. However, if you setup your access to the server and database as root you will not run into problems exporting/importing because you have the right access to do so.