# MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard python error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

There are two bugs in bugs.mysql.com related to this same error ([1](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66861) and [2](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67831)). They either provide no solution (#2) or a replacement of the .py that does not solve the problem (#1).

The error:

> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_mysql_re_grt.py", line 288, in wrap_routine_sql
>
> return "DELIMITER $$\n"+sql
>
> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

So: the line `"DELIMITER $$\n"+sql` produces the error `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`.

The error is in the line 288 of the file `db_mysql_re_grt.py`. [This is the original .py file](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/modules/db.mysql/db_mysql_re_grt.py#L288) from the mysql-workbench's github.

The call to `wrap_routine_sql` comes from [this other line](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/modules/db.mysql/db_mysql_re_grt.py#L347):

```
sql = result.stringByName("Create Procedure")
grt.begin_progress_step(0.1 + 0.9 * (i / total), 0.1 + 0.9 * ((i+0.5) / total))
grt.modules.MySQLParserServices.parseSQLIntoCatalogSql(context, catalog, wrap_sql(wrap_routine_sql(sql), schema_name), options)
grt.end_progress_step()
i += 0.5
```

Comment: check `sql` variable. I bet it's `None`.

Comment: looks like `sql` is `None` - the question is why? Can you please extract minimum subset of your db that issue can be reproduced and show it here? Aleternativly you can fill a bug report at bugs.mysql.com and attach your db privately.

Answer (score 0):

(not exactly a fix, but an alternative way to circumvent the error in my own question)

An alternative to the migration is: dump source to files -> import dump to destination db.

From the [original info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html), the steps are:

- Open MySQL Workbench
- Open source db
- Server -> Data Export
- Open destination db
- Create schema (the import does not create the schema for you)
- Server -> Data Import

In case of error `“Error querying security information” on Data Export`, the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521822/mysql-workbench-error-1142-error-querying-security-information-on-data-export) was to download the version 6.3.7 of the Workbench (and it worked).